# How to compare an IN list case sensitive

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The statement

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_field IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

ignores case, so records are also found when some_field is 'ABC' for example.

Placing a `COLLATE` after the list unfortunately produces a syntax error. Does anyone know how to compare an `IN` list case sensitive without changing the (insensitive) collation setting for the DB or single field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `COLLATE` after column name:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE some_field COLLATE <collation_name>_CS IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a1d65013192768fe4f355381b8c9eb3)**

Comment: should be  `<collation_name>_CS`, according to what op wants

Comment: @Lamak Thanks for spotting it

Comment: Long live the stackoverflow hive!